# Provide the same service instance under different tokens

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, dependencies, dependency-management

I have 2 interfaces:

```
export interface IUserService {
    ...
}

export interface IUserStorageService {
    ...
}
```

And a single service implementing both of them:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService implements IUserService, IUserStorageService {
    ...
}
```

*(This part seems to be irrelevant for the question, so it's just for the sake of completeness. I can easily convert interfaces to abstract classes to use them directly as tokens without additional injection tokens.)*
Now, since Angular doesn't support interfaces as tokens for providers, I have to create injection tokens:

```
export let USER_SERVICE: InjectionToken<IUserService> = new InjectionToken<IUserService>("user.service");

export let USER_STORAGE_SERVICE: InjectionToken<IUserStorageService> = new InjectionToken<IUserStorageService>("user-storage.service");
```

And now I'm able to map those injection tokens to the single service class globally in my `app.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({
    ...
    providers: [
        { provide: USER_SERVICE, useClass: UserService },
        { provide: USER_STORAGE_SERVICE, useClass: UserService }
    ],
    ...
})
export class AppModule {
    ...
}
```

And finally, I'm now able to inject the service under different interfaces to my components:

```
// Some component - sees service's API as IUserService
constructor(@Inject(USER_SERVICE) private readonly userService: IUserService) {
}

// Another component- sees service's API as IUserStorageService
constructor(@Inject(USER_STORAGE_SERVICE) private readonly userStorageService: IUserStorageService) {
}
```

The issue here is that Angular actually creates 2 instances of `UserService`, one for the each token, while I need `UserService` to be a single instance per app.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why do even you need to provide the same service under two different names? Since you need it to be a single instance anyway, what's preventing you from just providing it once?

Comment: @AakashJain: Because that single service implements 2 interfaces and different components of my app need to communicate with it using either of those interfaces.

Comment: That's still possible to do if you just provide it once.

Comment: @AakashJain: I've added to my question a sample of how I inject it into different components under each of those 2 interfaces. Please let me know if you know how to achieve the same by providing it only once.

Comment: I think you're overengineering things. But you can use `{provide: USER_STORAGE_SERVICE, useExisting: USER_SERVICE}`.

Comment: @JBNizet is right. You should either change your components to simply take `UserService`, or separate your implementations of `IUserService` and `IUserStorageService`. If the two have a lot in common, separate the common functionality out into a third service and inject it into both of them. Keep in mind that `InjectionToken`s are meant to let you inject non-classes. What you're trying to do isn't the intended usage at all.

Comment: @JBNizet: That did the trick, thank you! I've the feeling of overengineering as well, but haven't come up with a better solution. Do you have suggestions for the design I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Aakash asks the right question. If you feel user and user storage should be two different responsibilities (as you seem to think since you're defining two interfaces, and two injection tokens), then why do you put them both in the same implementation class? Using two classes would allow to simply inject those two classes. And if you feel a single class is enough because it's actually the same responsibility, then why not inject this unique class everywhere?

Comment: @JBNizet and @AakashJain: My underlying idea was that "retrieve users" (`IUserService`) and "store users" (`IUserStorageService`) is the single concern, since those are "CRUD" operations on the same entity (`User`) and in this case we usually put all in one class. That's why I preferred to have a single implementation (`UserService`). But only a few components needs to store users, while number of components needs to retrieve them and it's a good idea to keep interface API as minimal as needed and don't expose that extra operation to the components that don't need it.

Comment: I think we can all agree it's impossible to succeed with angular if you're opposed to over-engineering ;-) I definitely second your approach, and really needed to do the same. I had an 'ImageDirective' that I'm using for responsive design. I want to 'provide' sizing parameters to it by means of 'ImageSizeService' but since right now this is just width + height I want to incorporate it into my existing 'ProductFeatureService'. It would be terrible to provide 'ProductFeatureService' to my image directive because then I couldn't use it anywhere else. (I can always split them later)

Comment: I don't think this is overengineering at all! If `IUserService` and `IUserStorageService` are implemented by different classes, then `IUserStorageService` has to have a number of `setXYZ` methods that should be "visible" to `IUserService` but not to components subscribing to `XYZ: Observable<...>`. And so we are back to the original problem: how to have the same class present different interfaces to different part of the app.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had a very similar requirement: I was providing a service to a number of components - the service has a `dispatchEvent` function and a `subscribeToEvents` function. I want it to be clear that only the managing component can use `dispatchEvent()`, so the service `implements` two abstract classes (these can then be used as tokens - which is clearer than the injection token format) - one has dispatchEvents, the other has subscribeToEvents

```
providers: [
    {provide: AbstractSettingsManager, useClass: SettingsEventService},
    {provide: AbstractSettingsConsumer, useExisting: AbstractSettingsManager}
  ],
```

You can use the `useExisting` key, and keep in mind that it means "use the existing token"

The components will all have the same `ServiceEventService` instance, but as I'm providing the `AbstractSettingsManager`/`AbstractSettingsConsumer` the components will only have access (via TypeScript checks) to one or other of the services functions